# Cloud firestore query of Map returning empty snapshot in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I do a query to get a document by checking a Map key from firestore. I use a StreamBuilder for that. Both Id are the same in firestore and in flutter code. Do you have an idea why the snapshot is empty ? postSnapshot.data.documents.length is equal to 0, it returns [].

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .where('userlist.' + widget.user.uid, isEqualTo: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, postSnapshot) {
          if (postSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return _displaysLoading();
          }
          if (postSnapshot.hasData) {
           ...
          }
        }
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning no documents.  That's because your data doesn't have a boolean `true` as the value of the map.  It has "user1".  A query using `isEqualTo: true` will never match `true` to the string value you show here.

You will either need to make your query match the data and pass "user1", or make your data match the query by making the value a boolean `true`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .where('userlist', arrayContains: widget.user.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, postSnapshot) {
          if (postSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return _displaysLoading();
          }
          if (postSnapshot.hasData) {
           ...
          }
        }
    )
```

Comment: This isn't showing an array type field, so `arrayContains` will not work at all here.